# Is there a way to fix the email and title validation in my CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate my email and Title input field but it still aloows me to submit the page. Where is the error in the code please?

```
if(email == "") {
    printError("emailErr", "Please enter your email address");
} else {
    var regex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
    if(regex.test(email) === false) {
        printError("emailErr", "Please enter a valid email address");
    } else{
        printError("emailErr", "");
        emailErr = false;
    }
}

if(title == "Select") {
    printError("titleErr", "Please select your title");
} else {
    printError("titleErr", "");
    titleErr = false;
}


if((nameErr || emailErr || titleErr) == true) {
   return false;
}
```

I expect it to provide an error message when the submit button is clicked. Link to my entire code https://jsfiddle.net/lizzyblue02/spmygzdw/

Comment: You seem to be closing the `validateForm` function way too early in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall it works fine, I just had to make a couple of changes.

Your `input type="submit"` submits the form every time it is clicked, even if the form validation returned errors. I changed it in `input type="button"`, and the form is now submitted using JavaScript and only if the form validation returned no error.

As mentioned in the above comment, you also needed to close the validate function later in the function.

You can see [result here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4rc2ujn/).

Comment: you can also just disable the default behaviour of the input button by e.PreventDefault();